# Prove that n choose k is even for 0<k<n if and only if n is a power of 2

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that $\binom{n} k$ is even for all $k$ between $1$ and $n-1$, if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$.

I have tried strong induction on Pascal's triangle but I've got nowhere. I think that there is a generating function approach to this question that I'd like to find.

Comment: Have you shown either direction? It might be easy to show it in one direction first.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/341099/12042) to another instance of essentially this question sketches a proof by induction on Pascal’s triangle.